# TCL subst or eval command is not working in my case ..

Tags: tcl

```
subst or eval command is not working in my case .. 

% proc sum {a b} {
    return [expr $a+$b]
}
%
% set a 1
1
% set b 2
2
% sum $a $b
3

%
% sum {$a} {$b}
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"

%
% subst [sum {$a} {$b}]
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"   >>>>>>>>> Why i am unable to substitue the value
%

% eval [sum {$a} {$b}]
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "+"    >>>>>>>>> Why i am unable to substitue the value
%
```

I want to know why the above cases are not working for me .. subst command should do the variable  and command substitution . But why my variables are not substituting.

Can anyone Please Explain what is going on?

Comment: `sum [subst {$a}] [subst {$b}]` is the correct way. Or you could do `sum {$::a} {$::b}`

Comment: For some surprise try `set c 1; set d 2; sum {$c} {$d}`. It will report that this variables don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

First, you do understand why “`$a`“ isn't a value you can add to? It's not a number at all. (I don't mean `$a`, the instruction to read from a variable and substitute it, I mean the string consisting of a `$` followed by an `a`.)

When you put braces round things in Tcl, it means “don't do anything with this string at all; use it as-is”. Always. (Sometimes you're feeding that string into a command that evaluates, but not always.) When you put square brackets round things, it means evaluate that string as a script *immediately* and use the result of the script as the value to substitute. Always.

When you do:

```
subst [sum {$a} {$b}]
```

You need to understand that the call to `sum` is done while assembling the arguments to `subst`. That call produces an error, so the call to `subst` never happens. Similarly with the `eval` form you used.

If we use a somewhat less surprising form:

```
subst {sum {$a} {$b}}
```

Then you'll get this out: `sum {1} {2}`. `subst` doesn't understand the overall string as a script. On the other hand, with:

```
eval {sum {$a} {$b}}
```

In this case you get an error not from the `eval` as such, but rather from the fact that the call to `sum` inside is still erroneous.

I suppose you could do:

```
eval [subst {sum {$a} {$b}}]
```

**But really don't.** There's got to be a simpler and less error-prone way.

Answer (score 1):

You put the square braces `[]` to the wrong place (resp. you even don't need them in the `eval` case). In the way you wrote the commands the `sum {$a} {$b}]` is evaluated *before* the `subst` or `eval` command could evaluate the contents of `$a` and `$b`.

Correct is:

```
eval sum {$a} {$b}
```

or

```
sum [subst {$a}] [subst {$b}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand Tcl correctly.

`subst` takes a string and substitues all variables in it, right.
But you pass the result of `sum {$a} {$b}` into it, which fails.

So you could either `subst` each parameter before you call `sum`:

```
sum [subst {$a} {$b}]
```

Or modify the sum to do the evaluation for you:

```
proc sum {a b} {
    uplevel 1 [list expr $a + $b]
}
```

`expr` does an own round of evaluation, this is why you usually pass a litteral string (enclosed with `{}`) to it, but in this case we actually use this fact. `uplevel` executes the command in the context of the caller.

If you call a command, Tcl will replace the variables before the actuall call is made, so maybe this snippet could help you to understand Tcl a little bit better:

```
set a pu
set b ts
$a$b "Hello World!"
```