# Why the subst command only does variable substitution in my case?

Tags: tcl

Tcl's `subst` command should do command , variable , backslash substitution .

```
proc sum {a b} {
    return [expr $a+$b]
}

%
% set a 1
1
% set b 2
2

subst {sum {$a} {$b}}
```

`subst` command should do the variable and command subsdtitutions , Here why command substitution not happend  .

```
sum {1} {2}
```

`subst` command should do the variable and command subsdtitutions , Here why command substitution not happend  . why it is only substituting the variables ?

Comment: Did you have a look at your previous question? [TCL subst or eval command is not working in my case ..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632112/tcl-subst-or-eval-command-is-not-working-in-my-case)

Comment: Next time please *look* at the preview of your question being typed *before* posting -- I fixed the formatting for you but questions posted with such little attention to their appearance are the sure way to being ignored and downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Command substitution will look for the pattern `[...]` and replace it with the returned result of the command inside the brackets, but your string doesn't have any text that matches that pattern.

Comment: Hmm. I voted the duplicate but after seeing the other question it seems that this is the real answer. The other question is related but not a duplicate of this one.